# What keys are pressed (modifiers) in other events than action events?

Tags: java, swing, listener, keystroke

I would like to know if there is any way to find out if any keys or mouse buttons are pressed without using InputEvent.

For example: My application does not have focus but when it gains it I want to know whether the Ctrl key is pressed or not. This works in most conditions but not if the focus is gained via a click on the title bar (and this is exactly what I'm looking for).

Or: I start dragging a window and I want to know if Ctrl key is pressed or released during this drag.

I have tried listening for Keystrokes and using an AWTEventListener but that doesn't help since there is no information about the pressed keys.

Is there any way to get the pressed keys from Swing?
As far as I've searched I don't think there is because the modifiers are gathered in the toolkit directly from the OS generated event (getModifiers() in XWindow for example) but maybe I'm wrong.

There is this way: [GlobalKeyListener](http://biletnikov-dev.blogspot.ro/2009/09/global-hotkeys-for-java-applications_25.html) but it's much to complicated and also OS dependent.

Comment: Can you try this, InputMap inputMap = component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl"), "aSwingAction");
        component.getActionMap().put("Swing's AbstractAction", action);  Here you can bind a keystroke such as ctrl or alt to a Swing Action, you have to write a swing action which is invoke when you press this keystroke

Comment: Use an undecorated frame, then the KeyStrokes will be handled by Java. Of course you will need to implement your own "title bar" and support dragging yourself.

Comment: @rahulpasricha - I want it to also work when the window is not focused.

Comment: @camickr - Changing the title bars is not an option. I want to create a non intrusive library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only actual possibility I found is using https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/

This adds a native listener using JNI.

Answer (score 1):

The title bar is NOT a Swing component so you can't receive events when you use a Swing listener.

If you want to listen for events then you need to use a JFrame with Swing decorations:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
frame.getRootPane().addMouseListener(...);
```

Comment: The idea of the question was whether or not I can know if a key is pressed in any other way than by using an ActionEvent.
Your way won't help in the second case where I want to know whether a key was pressed during a drag event and also I don't want to change anything in my window. I want everything to be external.

Comment: Events from clicking on the title bar are not handled by Swing. It doesn't matter what kind of event you are trying to listen for, it won't work. As you said in your original question: *There is this way: GlobalKeyListener but it's much to complicated and also OS dependent.*  - the reason it is complicated is because it is NOT supported in Swing. I gave you a suggestion that shows how you can build a frame completely composed of Swing components so you can listen for the events. Its either that or the non Java solution.

Comment: Just ignore the title bar part for a second. The question is "What keys are pressed (modifiers) in other events than action events?". I thought maybe there is a method in the Toolkit which you can call at any time (with or without a listener) to find out what keys are pressed and I missed it.

Comment: 'I thought maybe there is a method in the Toolkit which you can call at any time' - not that I know of. You can listen for `KeyEvents` as they are generated and a `MouseEvent` will also indicate if Ctrl, Alt, Shift was pressed. But again I stress the title bar is NOT a Swing components so you can NOT listen for these events!

Answer (score 0):

What about listening for keys and setting some boolean variables. Then when you application gets focus you just check if the booleans are set.

For example

```
private boolean isCtrlDown;
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) {
        isCtrlDown = true;
    }
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
   if(e.getKeycode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) {
       isCtrlDown = false;
   }
}


public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
     if(isCtrlDown) {
         // Do what you wanted to do
     }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for the first case where focus is in another application and I click a title bar in my application.